# How can I plot the solutions of my ODE?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Consider the following code that solves an ODE.

```
DJ[x_, y_] := (y[x] + x^2) y'[x] - x^2 y[x] == (y'[x])^2

DJ[x, y]
```

> `-x^2 y[x] + (x^2 + y[x]) Derivative[1][y][x] == Derivative[1][y][x]^2`

```
solve = DSolve[DJ[x, y], y[x], x]
```

> `{{y[x] -> E^x C[1]}, {y[x] -> x^3/3 + C[1]}}`

How can I plot the above solutions?

Comment: Perhaps `Plot[Flatten[Table[y[x] /. solve /. C[1] -> p, {p, -2, 2}]], {x, -3,  3}]`

Comment: @Bill - recommend that you use `Evaluate` and `PlotLegends`, e.g., `Plot[Evaluate@
  Flatten@Transpose[
    Table[y[x] /. solve /. C[1] -> p, {p, -2, 2}]], {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: There are examples in the [docs for `DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html).  For example, under **Scope** > **Basic Uses** as well as elsewhere.